# regexp_replace / Substr extract string before and after dashes Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string  and I am not able to extract the single characters which is bounded by dashes. I wrote `Replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(string,.*-[[:alnum:]]-'),'-')` but it is not giving the expected output.
I need,

```
XTT-D-X-K-345ROCKVIEW-CA    Output = > D X K
RT-5-345REDE               Output = > 5
FT-5-3-345HOTELWI          Output = > 5 3
```

But I am getting

```
XTT-D-X-K-
RT-5-
FT-5-3-
```

I need to add something which I am not able to figure out.Maybe it can be done with just using regexp instead of using replace on regexp.

Comment: Few questions - are all the characters alphanumeric, or could you have something like XTT-4-#-C-233PLANET with required output 4 # C?  Also, are all the single characters consecutive? If not, what should be the output if the input is RT-3-5-INDIA-A-Z-CASH?

Comment: @mathguy Thanks for looking at my request. All will be alphanumber only no # or anything else.Yes all are single characters consecutive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use this:

```
SELECT Replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '\-([[:alnum:]]\-)+'), '-', ' ') as outstr
FROM (SELECT 'XTT-D-X-K-345ROCKVIEW-CA' AS str FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 'RT-5-345REDE' AS str FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 'FT-5-3-345HOTELWI' AS str FROM dual
```

Comment: Awesome! That works perfect!! Thank you once again for your quick help.Sir, can you tell me what exactly does that backslash do?

Comment: you can find info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#i1011021), It is Escape Character - Treats the subsequent metacharacter in the expression as a literal. Use a backslash (\) to search for a character that is normally treated as a metacharacter. Use consecutive backslashes (\\) to match the backslash literal itself